# Is there a way to make this code less taxing on the computer?

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I have some python to convert a Decimal number into a Hexadecimal, however, my computer takes forever and shuts off before the code even finishes. Is there a way to compact this code to less lines? I have Python 3.8.3 downloaded. The python is in a plain text (but **.py**) file and I am running it through terminal on macOS High Sierra (v10.13.6).

```
import math

dec = float(input("Decimal: "))

while(math.floor(dec/16) >= 0):
  x = "Hex: "
  rem = dec/16 - math.floor(dec/16)
  myHex = rem*16
  if myHex > 9 :
    if myHex == 10 :
      x += "A"

    if myHex == 11 :
      x += "B"

    if myHex == 12 :
      x += "C"

    if myHex == 13 :
      x += "D"

    if myHex == 14 :
      x += "E"

    if myHex == 15 :
      x += "F"

  else :
    x += str(myHex)  

print (x)
```

Comment: You know about the built-in `hex`, right?

Comment: Anyway, `math.floor(dec/16) >= 0` is always going to be `True`, hence the infinite loop

Comment: @DeepSpace You know hex will only take ints, right?

Comment: Yes, that was the goal. Thanks for the help

Comment: So, I should change it to '>' instead of '>=' right?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [struct](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwivg4b-5uPpAhVSGs0KHSQ9AwoQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F2%2Flibrary%2Fstruct.html&usg=AOvVaw2Bx1JYIyPhmt9WNjka9ehj) module:

```
import struct

f = float(input("> "))
print(hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', f))[0]))
```

Input:

```
> 234.345
```

Output:

```
0x436a5852
```

Comment: I have no idea how that works.